# Abgrenzung Zahladjektive von Pronomen

Tags: adjective

Im Buch "Crashkurs Rechtschreibung" des Duden-Verlags schreiben die Autoren:
"Die vier Zahladjektive **viel - wenig - ein - andere** werden in der Regel in allen Formen kleingeschrieben. Auch Pronomen wie **manche - jede - beide - einige** werden kleingeschrieben."

Als Beispiele werden aufgeführt:

- "Nur **wenige** eröffneten ein Konto." (Zahladjektiv)
- "Die Ausbilder mochten **manche** gern, die **beiden** aber nicht." (Pronomen)

Für mich sind alle genannten Wörter unbestimmte Mengenangaben. Mir fällt die gedankliche Abgrenzung schwer: Warum sind **viel** usw. Zahladjektive und **manche** usw. Pronomen?

Comment: Nice question! I can't write a complete answer, but here what I know. You can't distinguish between these depending on the meaning alone. Many can be used as *Indefinitpronomen* and *unbestimmte Zahladjektive*. The difference can be made only grammatically. *Unbestimmte Zahladjektive* are adjectives and thus can be preceded by the definite article: *viele Spieler > die vielen Spieler*; *Indefinitpronomen* on the other hand can't be preceded by the definite article: *viel Mut > *der viel Mut*. You can think of it as if the indefinite pronoun replaces the article.

Comment: Of course, pronouns can stand alone as in your examples *Die Ausbilder mochten **manche** gern, die beiden aber nicht*. In this example *Nur wenige eröffneten ein Konto*, *wenige* can be understood as a nominalized adjective and in this case *wenige* does not start with a capital letter. I think *die beiden* is also a nominalized adjective and not a pronoun!

Comment: I couldn't understand why *Duden* would consider *die beiden* a pronoun. So I have looked for your book and searched into it. It is very important to note that the book does not actually say that *die beiden* is a pronoun, or even *wenige* is an adjective. It just gives you examples for both cases which were mentioned as a single idea in one paragraph. So maybe it is better to understand *wenige* as a pronoun and *die beiden* as a nominalized adjective in your examples. I hope to quote what is in book precisely in case somebody wants to answer your question in detail.

Answer (score 9):

From *Crashkurs Rechtschreibung* I quote:

> Die vier Zahladjektive **viel – wenig – ein – andere** werden in der Regel in allen Formen kleingeschrieben. Auch Pronomen wie **manche – jede – beide – einige** werden kleingeschrieben.
>
> Nur **w**enige eröffneten ein Konto. Die **e**inen beklagten sich, die **a**nderen machten mit. Unter **a**nderem ... Den Ausbilder mochten **m**anche gern, die **b**eiden aber nicht

Your question is excellent because its answer has an easy part and a tricky part. Let's see:

First, I will start with the easy part. If you are looking for an easy rule to distinguish indefinite pronouns from indefinite numeral adjectives, here is a good one from *Pons- Die große Grammatik* and from this [article (Indefinitpronomen und unbestimmte Zahladjektive)](http://thumulla.com/home/indefinitpronomen_und_unbestimmte_zahladjektive.html) online: You can not distinguish between these depending on the meaning only. Many can be used as Indefinite pronouns and indefinite numeral adjectives. The distinction can be made only grammatically. Numeral adjectives are adjectives after all and thus can be preceded by the definite article *viele Spieler > die vielen Spieler*; indefinite pronouns on the other hand can not be preceded by the definite article *viel Mut > *der viel Mut*. You can think of it as if the indefinite pronoun replaces the article.

Indefinite pronouns can stand alone in the sentence (*Stellvertreter*) or can accompany another noun (*Begleiter*).

> Sie hat genug Geld. (*Begleiter*)
>
> Sie hat genug. (*Stellvertreter*)

According to the previous simple rule, we can say for sure that *beiden, einen, anderen* in your examples are nominalized adjectives and in this special case they do not start with a capital letter.

Now for the tricky part. Some words (e.g., *viel, wenig, manch*) are borderline cases ([Wiktionary)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/viel). According to [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-Indefinit.html), *viel, wenig* are not classified as indefinite pronouns but *manch* is (along with *all, alle, allesamt, andere, beide, einer, einige, etliche, ein bisschen, ein wenig, ein paar, etwas, irgendetwas, etwelche (veraltet), irgendein, irgendwelche, irgendwas, irgendwer, jeder, jedweder, jeglicher, jedermann, jemand, irgendjemand, kein, man, manch, mancher, mehrere, meinesgleichen, nichts, niemand, sämtlich, welche, wer, was*) . I will take *viel* as a representative for such words from now on. *Viel* is classified as an adjective (numeral adjective) in [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/viel) and in books like *Duden- die Grammatik* (along with with words like *einzeln, einzig, übrig, verschieden, gewiß, gesamt, ganz, halb, wenig, viel, zahlreich, zahllos,
ungezählt*). *Viel* is not listed among the indefinite pronouns neither in canoo nor in *Duden- die Grammatik*, but we see that in [Duden- Rechtschreibung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_zahlreich_vielerlei) and other sources, *viel* is considered to be an indefinite pronoun. In fact, we can not tell for sure whether *viel* and the likes are indefinite pronouns or indefinite numeral adjectives in certain cases.

Examples:

> Nur **wenige** eröffneten ein Konto
>
> Das haben schon **viele** erlebt

To make it more complicated, canoo considers *[andere](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-andere3.html), [beide](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-beide.html?MenuId=Word4263)* to be pronouns (declined like adjectives) even after the definite article, what goes clearly against *PONS* point of view:

> Die anderen (Leute) wussten es früher. Wir wollen das andere (Brot)
>
> Die beiden (Antworten) sind korrekt

canoo also considers *viel, wenig* to be undeclined adjectives in [examples](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html) like the following, what also goes against the above-mentioned rule:

> Ich habe viel/wenig Geld

In conclusion, there are different ways to classify such words. For example, in *Nur wenige eröffneten ein Konto*, *wenige* can be understood either as 1. a nominalized adjective (what maybe your book implies) or 2. an indefinite pronoun. Both are fair arguments and both are correct.

---

Ich zitiere aus *Crashkurs Rechtschreibung*:

> Die vier Zahladjektive **viel – wenig – ein – andere** werden in der Regel in allen Formen kleingeschrieben. Auch Pronomen wie **manche – jede – beide – einige** werden kleingeschrieben.
>
> Nur **w**enige eröffneten ein Konto. Die **e**inen beklagten sich, die **a**nderen machten mit. Unter **a**nderem ... Den Ausbilder mochten **m**anche gern, die **b**eiden aber nicht

Deine Frage ist eine gute Frage, denn sie besteht aus einem einfachen Teil und aus einem schwierigen Teil. Also, schauen wir uns das mal genauer an:

Ich fange zuerst mit dem einfacheren Teil an. Wenn du auf der Suche nach einer Regel bist, um unbestimmte Pronomen von unbestimmten Zahlwörtern zu unterscheiden, dann kann ich dir eine aus *Pons - die große Grammatik* empfehlen, die auch in diesem [Online-Artikel (Indefinitpronomen und unbestimmte Zahladjektive)](http://thumulla.com/home/indefinitpronomen_und_unbestimmte_zahladjektive.html) steht: Die Unterscheidung kann nicht allein anhand der Bedeutung getroffen werden. Viele Worte können sowohl als Pronomen als auch als Zahlwörter verwendet werden. Numerale sind Adjektive und daher kann ihnen ein bestimmter Artikel vorangehen: *viele Spieler > die vielen Spieler*. Unbestimmten Artikeln hingegen kann kein bestimmter Artikel vorangehen: *viel Mut > der viel Mut* ist keine grammatisch mögliche Konstruktion. Du kannst dir in etwa vorstellen, dass das unbestimmte Pronomen den Artikel in gewisser Weise ersetzt.

Unbestimmte Pronomen können im Satz allein stehen (als Stellvertreter) oder aber ein Nomen begleiten (Begleiter):

> Sie hat genug Geld. (Begleiter)
> Sie hat genug. (Stellvertreter)

Gemäß der einfachen obenstehenden Regel können wir mit Sicherheit sagen, dass in deinen Beispielsätzen *beiden*, *einen* und *anderen* nominalisierte Adjektive sind, die in diesem Spezialfall nicht groß geschrieben werden.

Nun zu dem schwierigen Teil: Manche Worte sind Grenzfälle ([Wiktionary)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/viel). [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-Indefinit.html) zufolge werden *viel* und *wenig* nicht als unbestimmte Pronomen eingeordnet, wohl aber *manch* (ebenso wie *all*, *alle*, *allesamt*, *andere*, *beide*, *einer*, *einige*, *etliche*, *ein bisschen*, *ein wenig*, *ein paar*, *etwas*, *irgendetwas*, *etwelche* (veraltet), *irgendein*, *irgendwelche*, *irgendwas*, *irgendwer*, *jeder*, *jedweder*, *jeglicher*, *jedermann*, *jemand*, *irgendjemand*, *kein*, *man*, *manch*, *mancher*, *mehrere*, *meinesgleichen*, *nichts*, *niemand*, *sämtlich*, *welche*, *wer*, *was*) . Ich werde von nun an *viel* als repräsentatives Beispiel für diese Worte verwenden. *Viel* wird von canoo und in der Duden-Grammatik als (numerales) Adjektiv eingeordnet (neben Wörtern wie *einzeln*, *einzig*, *übrig*, *verschieden, gewiß, gesamt, ganz, halb, wenig, viel, zahlreich, zahllos, ungezählt*). *Viel* wird weder von [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/viel) noch in der [Duden-Grammatik](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_zahlreich_vielerlei) als unbestimmtes Pronomen aufgeführt, dennoch wird es in [Duden-Rechtschreibung](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-andere3.html) und anderen Quellen als unbestimmtes Pronomen angesehen. Tatsächlich können wir in bestimmten Fällen nicht sicher sagen, ob *viel* und die anderen Worte unbestimmte Pronomen oder unbestimmte Numeraladjektive sind.

Beispiele:

> Nur **wenige** eröffneten ein Konto
>
> Das haben schon **viele** erlebt

Um es nun noch komplizierter zu machen: canoo sieht *[andere](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-andere3.html)* und *[beide](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-beide.html?MenuId=Word4263)* als Pronomen an (die genauso wie Adjektive dekliniert werden), selbst wenn sie auf einen bestimmten Artikel folgen, was ganz klar dem oben zitierten Standpunkt von *PONS* widerspricht:

> Die anderen (Leute) wussten es früher. Wir wollen das andere (Brot)
>
> Die beiden (Antworten) sind korrekt

Darüberhinaus sieht canoo *viel* und *wenig* als undeklinierte Adjektve in [Beispielen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html) wie den folgenden an, was ebenfalls gegen die oben zitierte Regel verstößt:

> Ich habe viel/wenig Geld

Zusammengefasst: Es gibt verschiedene Möglichkeiten, diese Worte einzuordnen. Nimm zum [Beispiel](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html):

> Nur wenige eröffneten ein Konto.

Hier kann *wenige* entweder 1) als nominalisiertes Adjektiv angesehen werden (was dein Buch wahrscheinlich vorschlagen würde) oder 2) als unbestimmtes Pronomen angesehen werden. Für beide Sichtweisen gibt es gute Gründe und beide sind korrekt.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer! Just want to mention that the op asked in german, so it might be appropriate to add a german explanation.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Since you are a good critic in this forum, your +1 means a lot to me, thank you. I know that my answer better be in German; However, I am afraid if I write this answer in German, it will be full of mistakes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know *that* :-). Because I think your answer is great, I thought it should have a german translation, so it can be accessible to non-english-speaking people as well. I took that as a legitimation to edit your post and add a german translation. If you feel this intrusion into your work is going too far, please feel free to remove it.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Now you know :-). On the contrary, thank you a lot for editing my answer.